# Encrypt Formula Fields with Platform Encryptiion

Tags: encryption, platform-encryption, shield-encryption

Are any types formula fields able to be encrypted via platform encryption? I have been looking for options, and so far, I have been unsuccessful in locating any documentation. If not, what have you been using to encrypt said values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula values are not stored in the database, and thus cannot be encrypted. Instead, formulas are generated the moment a query is performed (e.g. to view the record, in a report, etc). If you wanted an "encrypted formula", you'd have to use a custom text field, encrypt that field, then use a workflow rule/Process Builder/trigger/etc to specify the value to store. Note that cross-object formulas would behave oddly, since they could only be calculated the moment a record is created or updated.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox.  That makes total sense!!